# C#/C++ How can I get screenshots or rendered frames of all desktops (including inactive)

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to render my PC's desktops in real time as objects inside a Unity app. So far, I've been able to do this only at a display level (one unique desktop in Unity per physical monitor), via this C++ Unity plugin:
https://github.com/Clodo76/vr-desktop-mirror/blob/master/DesktopCapture/main.cpp

Output example:
[image: Example]

This works in mirroring my monitors, but prevents me from creating new virtual desktops in the Unity app without adding extra physical displays, so I'd like to find a way to render all of my Windows desktops in stead, even if they're not currently active.

Is there any way to do this? Though I know you can see thumbnails of created inactive desktops in the task view, I'm unsure if they're actually rendered in full resolution.

I'd prefer a pure C# answer, as I'm not very familiar with C++, but anything that works is fine.